# Regular expression for web scraping

Tags: regex, ruby, web-scraping

I am scraping a web site and need a REGEX to match the following data. Example: I need to grab

1. "Antoinette Denis" taking into account that some names are only one, without lastname.
2. "2019-07-16"
3. Comment, in this case the last paragraph "I have tried ..."

`{\"socialShareUrl\":\"https://au.trustpilot.com/reviews/5d2e47aeccd70b084c6255e8\",\"businessUnitId\":\"5bdc1f534c2c1b0001dc2b39\",\"businessUnitDisplayName\":\"Shapermint\",\"consumerId\":\"5d2e47ad9192678da1522016\",\"consumerName\":\"Antoinette Denis\",\"reviewId\":\"5d2e47aeccd70b084c6255e8\",\"stars\":5}\n\n\n\n\n        \n            \n\n\n    \n    \n    \n        \n            Antoinette Davis\n        \n        \n            \n                \n                1 review\n            \n                    \n    \n\n\n        \n\n    \n\n\n    \n        \n    \n\n    \n        \n    \n    \n        \n    \n    \n        \n    \n    \n        \n    \n    \n        \n    \n\n    \n        \n\n{\"publishedDate\":\"2019-07-16T21:54:54Z\",\"updatedDate\":null,\"reportedDate\":null}\n\n\n\n    \n    \n        \n\n{\"businessUnitDisplayName\":\"Shapermint\",\"consumerName\":\"Antoinette Denis\",\"informationRequestStatus\":\"none\",\"isVerified\":true,\"verificationSource\":\"invitation\"}\n\n    \n\n    \n\n    \n    \n        \n                Excellent product\n        \n        \n            I have tried spanks and just not comfortable in them but this really works and is very comfortable it was a very pleasant surprise\n        \n    \n\n    \n\n        \n            \n\n\n    \n        \n\n    \n        \n            \n                \n                Useful\n            \n        \n    \n\n        \n\n\n    \n        \n            \n                \n                Share\n            \n            \n        \n    \n\n        \n    \n        \n    \n    Reply`

I have this expression but I don't know how to work them together:

```
pattern_for_name = /"consumerName\\":\\"(?<name>\w* \w*)/
pattern_for_date = /"publishedDate\\":\\"(?<date>\d*-\d*-\d*)/
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not parse HTML with regexps. Here the significant part of your interest is located inside JSON objects, use this.

Assuming the whole string is assigned to `data`, do that:

```
jsons = data.scan(/{.*?}/).map(&JSON.method(:parse))
```

Now just retrieve your data back:

```
[jsons.first["consumerName"], jsons.last["publishedDate"]]
#⇒ ["Antoinette Denis", "2019-07-16T21:54:54Z"]
```